# FOR /L IN %SET% DO ( ... ) Doesn't do anything, it is just echoed?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a batch script that looks like this:

```
set F=Project_idem.exe
set I=1
set M=solution
set NSET=(3 20 1)
FOR /L %%N IN %NSET% DO ( START "idem" %F% -mode %M% -iterations %I% %%N )
```

What i want to do is run Project_idem.exe in a window called "idem" with with the last thing being the integer in 3,4,...,20. When i run the file it only prints out the lines? Like this:

```
FOR /L %N IN (3 20 1) DO (START "idem" Project_idem.exe -mode solution -iterations 1 %N )
```

And it doesn't do the actual iterations? How do I make it run the iterations? The OS is XP.
Ok solved... I had the step size in the wrong place. It should be (3,1,20). Thanks!!! (Can't believe I spent an hour on this :D )

Comment: I don't normally put the 'do' commands in brackets - is that allowed?

Comment: Great! You should click the tick next to David's answer below since that's the solution.

Answer (score 4):

From the help screen, it looks like it should be (3 1 20) instead of (3 20 1).

Comment: same answer than mine, faster, deserves +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug one problem at a time.

See `HELP FOR`

and try, at the command line,

```
FOR /L %a IN (3 20 1) DO @ECHO %a
```

and compare with

```
 FOR /L %a IN (3 1 20) DO @ECHO %a
```

This simple test should get you started.